# How to use Python to iterate through influxDB results

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

How can I iterate through the result set I get returned from influxDB? I get this result by using

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host=influx_host, port=influx_port,database='db')
q = client.query("select * from cpu limit 1")
```

> ResultSet({'(u'cpu', None)': [{u'usage_guest_nice': 0, u'usage_user': 0.90783871790308868, u'usage_nice': 0, u'usage_steal': 0, u'usage_iowait': 0.056348610076366427, u'host': u'xxx.xxx.hostname.com', u'usage_guest': 0, u'usage_idle': 98.184322579062794, u'usage_softirq': 0.0062609566755314457, u'time': u'2016-06-26T16:25:00Z', u'usage_irq': 0, u'cpu': u'cpu-total', u'usage_system': 0.84522915123660536}]})

and I want to get the usage_user value, the usage_system value etc. and insert them in an array.

Comment: Can you also post snippet where you execute the query?

Comment: What do you mean where do I execute? The IDE? It is in PyCharm

Comment: Are you using  rs.get_points() to get that result?

Comment: No, I use a query q = client.query("select * from events limit 1")

Comment: Remember you can filter by measurements or tags, check out this
http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resultset.html#filtering-by-measurement-and-tags in your case would be  ```cpu_points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='usage_system'))```

Comment: @julian salas I want to iterate through all of the values and keep them in an array

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to iterate through the `ResultSet` is by using its `get_points()` method, which can optionally filter by measurement or tags or both.

For example:

```
results = client.query("select * from cpu limit 1")
for measurement in results.get_points(measurement='cpu'):
    usage_system = measurement['usage_system']
    # do whatever with usage_system
```

See the official [InfluxDB-Python](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resultset.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to export the results in JSON format with the **raw** option, then split them at commas, add them in the array, and iterate through them. I had to use the dataframes for this

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import pandas as pd
client = InfluxDBClient(host=influx_host, port=influx_port,database='db')
q = "select * from cpu limit 1"
result = pd.DataFrame(client.query(q, chunked=False).raw)
```

I hope this will help somebody else because the documentation is not very clear how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I concur wiht Peterdn as there is simpler way in client itself that goes like this

```
results = client.query("select * from cpu limit 100")
resultInList = results.get_points(measurement='cpu')
print(type(resultInList)
--->>> <class 'list'>
```

last print statement showing that you have list of response data.....it means it is converting your Resultset in list which you can easily iterate through without using Pandas...

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the [docs](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resultset.html) and by @peterdn, `InfluxDBClient.query()` function returns a `ResultSet` object.

Using `rs.get_points()` will return a **generator** for all the points in the ResultSet.

**Example:**

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
cpu_points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='cpu'))
```

You can even filter by measurement, tags or even both as follows:

**Filter by measurement:**

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
cpu_points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='cpu'))
```

**Filter by tags:**

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
cpu_influxdb_com_points = list(rs.get_points(tags={"host_name": "influxdb.com"}))
```

**Filter by tags and measurement:**

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='cpu', tags={'host_name': 'influxdb.com'}))
```

Hope this helps.